# Open ID & Person Domain Names

Tags: openid

I've got a myOpenID account and I want my OpenID to be `myname.com` instead of `myname.myopenid.com`.

I've got it working by putting these tags in the header of my website homepage:

```
<link rel="openid.server" href="http://www.myopenid.com/server" />
<link rel="openid.delegate" href="http://myname.myopenid.com/" />
```

I then managed to log in to blogger.com to add a comment to someone's post and my name on the comment appeared as my domain name (or OpenID name) instead of my full name that I have set up on myOpenID. Is that normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on if you've set your myOpenID persona with a nickname and if the site you're using the OpenID on accepts or uses nickname or just uses what your OpenID is.

To set up a nickname for your persona:

- Log into myOpenID
- Click **Your Account**
- Click **Registration Personas**
- Set yourself up a registration persona/identity/profile
- When editing, fill in the part labelled **Nickname**

Now next time when you're signing in with OpenID you'll be asked which of your personas you want to sign in to the final site with. Your nickname/display name will be reflected if you've set it up in the above mentioned steps.